# Start IPython in a Python program, connect with IPython Notebook

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I think it's possible to embed IPython instances in Python programs and 'connect' to them with a console/notebook/qt-console. I tried the IPython docs but didn't get to it.

I would like to start IPython in a 'regular' Python program, give it access to the program's namespace, connect with a IPython notebook and continue the Python program after I closed/quit the notebook.

```
dataframe = run_some_program_get_data()

# start IPython with access to 'dataframe'

# continue program with dataframe  
dataframe.to_csv('file.txt')
```

How can I start an IPython kernel in a normal Python program? And how can I set to which kernel an IPython notebook should connect?

Comment: try to use ipdb, just set trace point in place where you need interactive access to script with ipdb.set_trace()

Comment: I'll look into it. There is not really a straightforward way to implement what I described, right? I googled a lot and didn't get anywhere.

Comment: But looks like similiar, anyway I don't know how to help you with ipython notebook, sorry.

Comment: hey , did you success to connect to iPythone in a webpage template_?

Answer (score 0):

I'm running the latest IPython 2.1 with Anaconda 2.0.1.

There are some [directions on this page](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-1.1.0/interactive/public_server.html) which help you set up a IPython instance for hosting purposes.  Here is how to tweak this to run locally.

run "`ipython profile create nbserver`" at the terminal/command prompt

In the profile directory just created, (usually ~/.ipython/profile_nbserver) edit the file ipython_notebook_config.py. By default, the file has all fields commented; the minimum set you need to uncomment and edit is the following:

```
c = get_config()

# Kernel config
c.IPKernelApp.pylab = 'inline'  # if you want plotting support always

# Notebook config
c.NotebookApp.ip = '*'               #or keep it 'localhost'
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False
# It is a good idea to put it on a known, fixed port
c.NotebookApp.port = 9999
```

Then open 2 terminals/command_prompts so you can check if it works.  In the first type (don't put an underscore in either line)

```
ipython console -i --profile nbserver
```

then type in that window `a = 1`

and the 2nd

```
ipython console -i --profile nbserver --existing
```

type `print(a)`

**and yes... you can replace the word "console" with "notebook" or "qtconsole"** 
(but for qt-console take out the -i switch)